# How to control a timer in visual basic where the time interval of the timer is set by the user from a textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, logic, user-input

I am new to visual basic and I am trying to run a series of codes at a time interval set by the user which the latter can change any time from the text box. please find attached the interface I've created.

[image: user input form]

Comment: `I am trying to...` and where is the code which actually tries to do anything?  Hard to guide you without the code

Comment: Show us what you've tried already. We will not create entiore solutions, but we will help you fixing bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to set the interval value every time that the user puts a right **Integer** value inside the **TextBox** by handling the `TextBox.TextChanged` event (you can add or not a proper error-handling).

An example:

```
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub ResetTimerInterval(ByVal tmr As Timer, ByVal interval As Integer)
    If (tmr IsNot Nothing) Then
        With tmr
            .Stop()
            .Enabled = False
            .Interval = interval 
            .Enabled = True
            .Start()
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim value As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text, value) Then
        Me.ResetTimerInterval(value)
    End If

End Sub
```

---

If you also want to know the current Interval, you can track it by adding a Property:

```
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Property TimerInverval As Integer
    Get
        Return Me.timerIntervalB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If (value <> Me.timerIntervalB) Then
            Me.timerIntervalB  = value
            Me.ResetTimerInterval(value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
' Backing field.
Private timerIntervalB As Integer

Private Sub ResetTimerInterval(ByVal tmr As Timer, ByVal interval As Integer)
    If (tmr IsNot Nothing) Then
        With tmr
            .Stop()
            .Enabled = False
            .Interval = interval 
            .Enabled = True
            .Start()
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim value As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text, value) Then
        Me.timerIntervalB = value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your precious help. Will try it.

Comment: @luvin I'm glad to help. please remember to mark my answer as accepted IF it solved the problem, thanks and welcome to SO.